# Extract & store links from Beautiful Soup nested objects

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape and save links from a webpage.  The links are organized as widgets in a blogroll section of a blog.  I've figured out how to create a list of some Beautifulsoup objects but can't extract the links from that subset of objects.

I've spent many hours trying various types of find, find_all, and re-souping these objects.

```
req = Request(url , headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11'})
document = urlopen(req, context=ctx)
html = document.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")



tags = soup.find_all(attrs={"class":"xoxo blogroll"})
print(type(tags))
#this is a <class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>


count = 0
for tag in tags:
    print(type(tag))
    # this is a <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
    print('this is tag: ', tag)#tester print

 ''' 
    this returns things like:
this is tag:  <ul class="xoxo blogroll">
<li><a href="http://blog.jaibot.com/">ANOIEAEIB</a></li>
<li><a href="http://commonsenseatheism.com/">Common Sense Atheism</a></li>
<li><a href="http://lesswrong.com">Less Wrong</a></li>
<li><a href="http://thelastpsychiatrist.com/">The Last Psychiatrist</a></li>
</ul>
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
this is tag:  <ul class="xoxo blogroll">
<li><a href="http://alicorn.elcenia.com/board/index.php">Alicornutopia</a></li>
<li><a href="http://unsongbook.com">Unsong</a></li>
<li><a href="https://parahumans.wordpress.com/">Worm</a></li>
</ul>

    '''
```

I want to extract and print all the url's from each 'tag' and then save them into my sqlite3 database.

Comment: can you share the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding an attribute selector to it so you get child hrefs of parents with that class.

```
links = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('.blogroll [href]')]
```

It is likely you can use a slightly faster

```
links = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('.blogroll a')]
```

Comment: You, sir/ma'am, are a genius.  What's the best way for me to get good at web scraping?  Some others have suggested reading through the beautiful soup documentation and working through the examples.